# Accessing odoo fields using eval from another module

Tags: python, odoo-12, odoo-13

Could somebody help me understand the purpose of this line?
I can see that it is referring to a field in accounts then the model account_move then the field amount_total.

I am trying to port this module from v12 to v13 but I get an error that amount_total does not exist.
The field amount_total exists in that model

`<field name="ks_record_field" eval="ref('account.field_account_move__amount_total')" />`

The original field in the module I am porting is this.

`<field name="ks_record_field" eval="ref('account.field_account_invoice__amount_total')" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the data file field [documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/data.html#field) :

> If a `ref` attribute is provided, its value must be a valid [external id](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/data.html#field), which will be looked up and set as the field’s value.
> Mostly for [Many2one](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/orm.html#odoo.fields.Many2one) and [Reference](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/orm.html#odoo.fields.Reference) fields.

> The `eval` attributes simply evaluates whatever Python expression it is provided and sets the result as the field’s value.
> The evaluation context contains various modules (`time`, `datetime`, `timedelta`, `relativedelta`), a function to resolve [external identifiers](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/glossary.html#term-external-identifiers) (`ref`) and the model object for the current field if applicable (`obj`).

When the data file is executed, Odoo will try to evaluate the expression specified by `eval` attribute and call `xmlid_lookup` which will return (`id`, `res_model`, `res_id`) or raise `ValueError` if not found.

The `Total` field external identifier is not present in the database (not created or deleted) or has been modified.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Kenly answer, informations of models and fields in odoo are stored in the database and when odoo saves them they have a special XML-ID structure that you can use to retrieve them quickly.

- model:  prefix `model_` contacatenated with the name of the model replacing point by underscore

  ```
   my.model.name --------->  model_my_model_name
  ```

You can check `ir.model.access.csv` we always use it.

- field: prefix `field_` concatenated withe  `name of the model + underscore + name of the field`

  ```
    my_field_name ----->  field_my_model_name_my_field_name
  ```

And of course when you refer to a model that is created in another app you need to give a full XML-id like you did `account.field_account_invoice__amount_total` because `account.invoice` is defined in `account` module in older version of Odoo, and you are getting this error because in V13 model `account.invoice` is merged into `account.move` `ref` will look for the field in database and it will not find it because there is no such model anymore.

I hope this help you too.